# Caffeine Cache, get oldest element

Tags: java, caching, caffeine

Since the concurrentedLinkedHashmap authors do advice to switch to caffeine if using java 8.
I wanted to know how I can get the oldest element of the cache.
(In the LinkedHashMap I'm able to remove the first element of the iterator to achieve this).

I, unfortunately, didn't find anything in the caffeine documentation.

Comment: See [Policy](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Policy), e.g. to persist the hottest entries for a warm restart.

Comment: But if I don't want that the entries destroy themselves automatically after time. I tried cache.oldest but the method did not exist .

Comment: cache.policy().eviction().get().coldest(1) will peek. The cache will evict automatically at some point if bounded.

Comment: Is there a way to set a cache to a max size and redirect the data he would throw away to another data storage?

Comment: Yes, you can use a CacheWriter or RemovalListener. The latter is async.

Comment: can you post "cache.policy().eviction().get().coldest(1) will peek." in an answer so that I can accept it as the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks, but its not fair to get points since I wrote the code in question. You should answer it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cache.policy().eviction().get().coldest(1)
```

will return the oldest element.

Additionally, it is possible to add a CacheWriter or RemovalListener to handle the removal of the oldest element after a certain time or after a certain number of elements:

```
new CacheWriter<Long, List<IOperation>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void write(@NotNull final Long key, @NotNull final List<IOperation> value)
                {
                    //On addition
                }

                @Override
                public void delete(@NotNull final Long key, @Nullable final List<IOperation> value, @NotNull final RemovalCause cause)
                {
                    //On removal
                }
            })
```